# Update page with AJAX on link click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm making a Debt management app and I have `@opened_debts` and `@all_debts` (opened and returned debts) in my controller.

By default I load only `@opened_debts` on page. But also I have a link for showing all debts on a page.

```
<a href="#" id="show_all_debts">Show all debts</a>
```

I want page to reload `debts_div` with `@all_debts` after clicking this link.

If I make a `<script>` tag with `click event` in the bottom of a page to load it with

```
$('#debts_div).replaceWith('<%= j render @all_debts %>');
```

Rails in fact renders all debts and make them invisible for user until he click the link. But it makes page loading slower with all this huge script.

Can I load this list without rendering it on a page until user clicks link?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use rails_ujs

```
<%= link_to "Show all depts", model_path(), :remote => true %>
```

then your request will be sent as ajax. create a view for js with

_index.html

```
<div>some code</div>
```

inside index.html.erb to make DRY

```
<%= render :partial => 'index.html' %>
```

index.js.erb to make DRY

```
$('#debts_div).replaceWith('<%= j( render :partial => 'index', :format => :html ) %>');
```

that should work

Comment: Great! It works. Thank you! One more question: now I have in `index.html.erb` file `@opened_debts` which opened by default and in `index.js.erb` file `@all_debts`. How I can reload `@opened_debts` again via ajax? How I can trigger via link what variable i want to render? Thanks!

Comment: create a partial `_index.html` and you could use it with `index.html.erb` and also inside `index.js.erb`. I've extended the answer. see below